# Android 3D acceleration in androVM with primusrun?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, android, hybrid-graphics

I have been trying an Android Virtual Machine called [androVM](http://androvm.org) on an Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit laptop with Intel/Nvidia hybrid graphics configuration as the guest OS (details on the graphic cards below). I tested some of the graphics-intense applications, like Angry Birds, and AnTuTu, a benchmarking application, running `virtualbox` and `AndroVMplayer` with `primusrun`, but they seem really slow, no difference whatsoever as when run without `primusrun`. I have also tried `optirun`, which simply crashes with a segfault. How can I enable OpenGL acceleration for this VM in my hybrid graphics system?

The AndroVM version I am running is this one:

> androVM_vbox86tp_4.1.1_r6.1-20130222-gapps-houdini-flash.ova

And I am following the installation instructions as explained here:
[AndroVM 20130222 release | AndroVM blog](http://androvm.org/blog/blog/2013/02/23/androvm-20130222-release/)

Under Virtualbox, I have the switched Graphics options set to 128MB Video Memory and Enabled 3D Acceleration and 2D Acceleration. My host BIOS has its virtualisation options activated. Here are my hardware details:

```
sudo primusrun lshw -class display

*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GT218 [GeForce 310M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:d3000000-d307ffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 18
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:52 memory:d3400000-d37fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:e080(size=8)
```

When using `optirun ./AndroVMplayer`, I get this:

```
[VGL] WARNING: The OpenGL rendering context obtained on X display
[VGL]    :8 is indirect, which may cause performance to suffer.
[VGL]    If :8 is a local X display, then the framebuffer device
[VGL]    permissions may be set incorrectly.
Got command 1002
Got command 1002
Got command 1
Got command 1002
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And here are the details of my virtualbox installation:

```
 dpkg -l virtualbox* | grep ii    

ii  virtualbox                                4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.2                               x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
ii  virtualbox-dkms                           4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.2                               x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
ii  virtualbox-guest-additions                4.1.12-1                                             transitional package for virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
ii  virtualbox-guest-additions-iso            4.1.12-1                                             guest additions iso image for VirtualBox
ii  virtualbox-guest-dkms                     4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.2                               x86 virtualization solution - guest addition module source for dkms
ii  virtualbox-guest-utils                    4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.2                               x86 virtualization solution - non-X11 guest utilities
ii  virtualbox-guest-x11                      4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.2                               x86 virtualization solution - X11 guest utilities
ii  virtualbox-qt                             4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.2                               x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
```

If I run it with `optirun`, I get the following error:

```
> [VGL] WARNING: The OpenGL rendering context obtained on X display
> [VGL]    :8 is indirect, which may cause performance to suffer. [VGL] 
> If :8 is a local X display, then the framebuffer device [VGL]   
> permissions may be set incorrectly.
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glCompileShader:351
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderiv:1215
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderInfoLog:1238
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1382
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glCompileShader:351
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderiv:1215
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderInfoLog:1238
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1382
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1382
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glCompileShader:351
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderiv:1215
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderInfoLog:1238
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1382
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1382
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glCompileShader:351
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderiv:1215
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderInfoLog:1238
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1382
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1382
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1382
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glCompileShader:351
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderiv:1215
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderInfoLog:1238
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1382
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1382
> error 0x501
> sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1913
> error 0x501 AndroVMplayer: ../../src/xcb_conn.c:180: write_vec:
> Assertion `!c->out.queue_len' failed. Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: I corrected my output to what I get when running `sudo primusrun lshw -class display` and both cards show up. Also, when I run `primusrun firefox` I get about 40-50fps on this website http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/aquarium/aquarium.html. I only get about 5fps without `primusrun`.

Comment: hmmm - maybe not required - have you got the hardware enable opengl setting defined in androvm as per http://androvm.org/blog/androvm-documentation/ ?

Comment: Yep, when I call `./AndroVMplayer` for the first time on a fresh VM, I click on "Enable Hardware Acceleration".

Comment: ... and you have followed the hardware opengl section in that link to setup your network and running via the run.sh script - or a variant of the script that uses primusrun ?

Comment: Beginning with the 20130208 release, the AndroVMplayer tool can now configure it. I call `primusrun ./AndroVMplayer`.

Comment: Are you running the VM headless (i.e. without a window showing)?

Comment: Check with Intel Hardware Acceleration http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681 Scroll down ...

Comment: 2D Acceleration should be disabled, methinks. Only 3D.

Comment: Still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

openGL uses specific rules when running an android environment. I'm not able to answer your question fully, but I can recommend you to an Android dev kit. developer.android.com/sdk/‎
Once this is set up, it will automatically configure your setup for optimum use of the rendering, and it can supply a 3d Android environment.

Answer (score 1):

You colud try **[GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)**. It is only one click to set-up and runs in x86-mode.

It is really fast Android emulator.